# HTML: Same Page Anchoring and using Tab Key

Tags: html

I am using a  link to jump to the content section of the page. It works fine; however, in IE and Chrome, after the jump if I press Tab it goes back to .

link : `<a href="#anchortext">Skip to Content</a>`

Content Location `<a id="anchortext" class='hidden'>Content</a>`

Any Idea?

Comment: So where should the second Tab take you? If there are no other focusable elements, then the second Tab takes you to the link. What should happen instead?

Comment: to the place where the <a href="#anchortext">Skip to Content</a> takes you to

Answer (score 4):

I suspect it has to do with the tab indexes of existing html elements on the page - clicking on an anchor tag as the one you specify above will take you down to the relevant section, but then pressing tab will take you to the first available tab stop (usually a link or form input item), which could very easily be back at the top of the page.

If you refresh the page and press tab once, you'll be taken to the first tab index enabled element of the page - I'm guessing that'll probably be the same section you were being taken to in your original question...

Comment: Yes in IE and Chrome, after I move to a section and press tab it takes me to the 1st Tab index element. However, this is not the case with Firefox. Any Fixes? for IE and Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a matter of different handling of internal links in browsers, and seems to fall into the category of behavior not defined in specifications, hence browser-dependent.

When you have focused on a link (usually, with tabbing) and hit enter to follow the link, browsers may or may not retain the focus. You can see the difference in behavior by using a CSS rule like `:focus { background: yellow; }`.

If the focus is retained (which is somewhat illogical, as the focused element may well be out of sight), a tab will take you to the next focusable element on the page (“next” in the sense of tabbing order).

If focus is lost, it may be treated as giving focus to the entire page (an IE oddity), or as having no focus. Either way, hitting tab will take you to the first focusable element on the page (as per the tabbing order).

I’m afraid there’s nothing you can do on a page to change this. It’s between the user and the browser.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there's no way of doing that using only html.

So, i made a javascript script using jquery.
When the user clicks on the jump item, i look for the next link or the next link inside a specific element and put a focus on it.
This solves my problem with Chrome (>25) and IE (>7) and of course Firefox does the excelent job of interpret the tab action correctly.

```
$("#jumpToMenu").on("keydown", function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(keyCode == 13) { 
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $("#myMenuToJump").find('a:first').focus();
    }
}).on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#myMenuToJump").find('a:first').focus();
});
```

Hope this helps...